# Auto increment plugin nextCount not found

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I am using the mongoose-auto-increment plugin and I am using TypeScript Node.js and I have installed the needed typed definitions but when I try to get the next count of the auto increment, I get this

```
Property 'nextCount' does not exist on type 'Model<Document>'
```

My schema is the one from the example:

```
let bookSchema = new Schema({
    author: { type: Number, ref: 'Author' },
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    publishDate: Date
});

bookSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Book');
var Book = connection.model('Book', bookSchema);

//// error here
Book.nextCount(function(err, count) {
});
```

My tsconfig.json is like so

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types" : ["node", "socket.io"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you  using mongoose-auto-increment plugin ?

Comment: yes and i have installed this as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: plugin last updated on 4 year before. can you explain why do you need this plugin ? we can do same thing manually with more customization

Comment: well i want an auto increment id, im storing chat messages here and i am pushing to the database once there is like around 50 messages to do so. In case the user wants to edit or delete i need a reference id and i know there is the _id in mongo by default but since im not pushing for each message, i need an auto increment part.

Comment: and not to mention im using mongoose, so.

Comment: mongo always maintain _id (primary, indexed, unique, hex value) and __v (for revison, number value), either you supplied or not. plugin only facilitate to read  _id as numeric form by an interal counter and getter setter methods. but still _id is Hex internally.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of that, but is the id predictable?

Comment: yes .save and .findOneAndUpdate or other mongoose method return updated/saved document and simply ready _id from returned value also _id is always incremented hex you can use it to sorting etc.

Comment: My problem still exists, i am not pushing for every message, i am pushing in batches, so i need to know the id's before inserting and also i need to know that they would be the same after inserting.

Comment: mongo/mongoose provide insert Many/bulk that also return inserted objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ObjectId` and set `_id` for every chat message before saving batch:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

messages.forEach(message => {
  message._id = message._id || ObjectId()
})

// call you method which save batches
saveBatch(messages)
```